# DB2 - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory - The DDM command is not supported

Tags: database, spring, rest, db2

I try to connect my rest application to DB2 database. I use Tomcat 9 to test my application.
**IMPORTANT** : I work into a virtual machine.
I set the context.xml with the jndi configuration:

**Context.xml**

```
<Resource name="jdbc/reeval" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
      auth="Container" username="XXX" password="XXX" 
      driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" 
      url="jdbc:db2://host.sample.fr:4461/DB2PROA" />
```

When my application try to execute a SQL request, I have this error message:

```
16:26:49,502 DEBUG SqlExceptionHelper:124 - Unable to acquire JDBC Connection [n/a] 
**java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory ([jcc][t4][20104][11269][3.65.131] La commande DDM n'est pas prise en charge.  Point de code de la commande DDM non prise en charge : 0x106d. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=58014**) 
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2303) 
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2043) 
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1543) 
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) 
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386) 
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:84) 
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:109) 
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:47) 
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146) 
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172) 
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148) 
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1934) 
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1903) 
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1881) 
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:925) 
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342) 
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2622) 
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2605) 
        at .....
**Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientException: [jcc][t4][20104][11269][3.65.131] La commande DDM n'est pas prise en charge.  Point de code de la commande DDM non prise en charge : 0x106d. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=58014** 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.cd.a(cd.java:323) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.cd.a(cd.java:387) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.lb(z.java:3142) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.y(z.java:763) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.n(z.java:674) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.a(z.java:475) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.a(z.java:118) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.c(b.java:1351) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:1222) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:789) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:761) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:422) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:397) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(b.java:335) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:233) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:199) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:475) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:116) 
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38) 
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:257) 
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2313) 
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2299) 
        ... 73 more 
16:26:49,510  WARN SqlExceptionHelper:129 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
```

Comment: When you say you work _into_ a virtual machine, do you mean the program is running on it, or the database or both?

Comment: Can you prove that the database DB2PROA exists and is connectable from the command-line from both local and remote? (outside of jdbc). Can you show that the DB2-instance concerned is listening on port 4461 ?   If you are connecting to Db2 on Z/OS then edit the question to specify which is the Db2 server version number.

Comment: You seem to be using the jdbc 3.0 driver that is shipped with Version 10.1 fixpack 5. You might want to try with a jdbc 4.0 driver, if your Db2 server is a recent version. Specify your Db2 server operating system (i-series, or z/os , or LUW etc).

Comment: @Scrambo : I work into a Virual Machine.

Comment: @mao : This is a DB2 Connect installed by the client. I try with the database Developement viex of Eclise to connect on it, by it failed. The DBA give the configuration, and the port is 4461, but I have no way to check that :(  The client give me the driver, I have a 3.65.131 and a 4.15.134 version of db2 Driver.

Comment: I find the solution. The port was wrong, I was 446 instead of 4461..